# How could I calculate several means using one set of user inputs?

Tags: c, mean

I am trying to calculate an arithmetic, geometric, and harmonic mean as well as a standard deviation, after prompting a user to input 5 integers.

I have the arithmetic mean working well. Its the others after it that are troublesome.. I am almost positive it is because of my structuring, but I just am not sure what to change after researching online and in my textbook... and any help is appreciated with this!

Here is the code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float a_mean;
float g_mean;
float h_mean;
float st_dev;
sum1 = 0; sum2 = 0; sum3 = 0;
float data[100];
n = 5;
int i;

int main()
{

    printf("Please Enter Five Integers:\n"); /* Prompts user input */

            for ( i = 0; i < n; ++i)
                {
                    scanf("%f", &data[i]);
                    sum1 = sum1 + data[i];
                }
            a_mean = sum1 / n;

                {
                    sum2 = sum2 * data[i];
                }
            g_mean = pow(sum2, 1 / n);

                {
                    sum3 = sum3 + ( 1 / data[i] );
                }
            h_mean = n / sum3;

    printf("Arithmetic mean: %0.2f\n", a_mean);
    printf("Geometric mean: %0.2f\n", g_mean);
    printf("Harmonic mean: %0.2f\n", h_mean);

    return 0;
}
```

I know its probably something basic with my for-structuring, but I simply don't know a lot about this stuff yet, so thanks in advance

**Also, disregard the fact that I haven't attempted to form my calculation/output for the standard deviation yet. Thanks

Comment: Ok thanks everyone, I minimized global variables, moved my loops in together and did some tweaking, and my arith and harm means both work, but geo gave me 0.00, does that formula look flawed as far as coding goes? Thanks

Comment: Yes, your logic for geometric mean is flawed. Think about what happens the first time through the loop - sum2 is 0, so sum2 * data[0] will be 0. So on the next pass through the loop sum2 is still 0 ...

Comment: sum2 += sum2 * data[i];

Comment: sorry I pressed enter..meant this all to be one comment. Anyways, then I have      g_mean = pow(sum2, 1 / n);   for the final calculation. This gives me a value, when tested, within + or - ~2 from what the actual geo. mean should be.

Comment: That surprises me. 0+0 is still 0.


pow(sum2, 1/n) is also problematic. 1 and n are both integers which means that 1/n will be an integer division. 1/n will be 0 for any value of n > 1. 1.0/n would force floating point division which will give you the fractional result you need.

Comment: Forgot to tell you, I changed sum2 to = 1.. however would this not alter the final result since that 1 is being added on?

Comment: That makes more sense. But yes, you're right, what you've now implemented sounds like it still isn't the formula for geometric mean so it's unsurprising you're getting the wrong answer!

Comment: sum2 *= data[i]; with sum2 was the solution btw

Answer (score 1):

Either do all of your summing inside the one for loop
or do three for loops.

Since you are beginning try both!

```
Here is the code:
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float a_mean;
float g_mean;
float h_mean;
float st_dev;
sum1 = 0; sum2 = 0; sum3 = 0;
float data[100];
n = 5;
int i;

int main()
{

    printf("Please Enter Five Integers:\n"); /* Prompts user input */

            for ( i = 0; i < n; ++i)
                {
                    scanf("%f", &data[i]);
                    sum1 = sum1 + data[i];
                    sum2 = sum2 * data[i];
                    sum3 = sum3 + ( 1 / data[i] );
                }

            a_mean = sum1 / n;
            g_mean = pow(sum2, 1 / n);
            h_mean = n / sum3;

           printf("Arithmetic mean: %0.2f\n", a_mean);
           printf("Geometric mean: %0.2f\n", g_mean);
           printf("Harmonic mean: %0.2f\n", h_mean);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might also want to separate the input from the processing.  Have one for loop that just does the scanning and another for loop that does all the summing (using the values stored in the array )

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken there are also some gotchas with integer division which will lead to unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the for loop will only run the scanf, and then change sum1. You need to move your `sum2 = sum2 * data[i]` and `sum3 = sum3 + (1 / data[i])` into the body of the for loop (Inside the {}s right after the for loop).

Comment: Thanks for the help, however I just made this modification and the cmd prompt stops working...

Comment: Nevermind -  I fixed this part. Anyways, the IDE I'm using launches CMD Prompt, and in that instance it gave me the error command prompt has stopped working, but I fixed that with the globals and types.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - your code doesn't compile, you're missing a bunch of types in the global variables. Second - you can't break up the loop and continue just by using curly brackets, the few sets you have after the first loop would just be executed once as normal code, so the other sums aren't collected properly.

As for style - try to use less globals, it's a bad habit

Comment: Alright I'll try to fix this, and thanks for the style tip, I know those kinds of things are important to nail down starting off, appreciate it.